# ASP.NET MVC4 - form design

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to develop a page on ASP.NET( MVC 4)

I have got a screen whose top section has got data entry fields and bottom  section has got data to display on the grid.

When i add data using top section , it will refresh bottom section ( grid).

when i will select a row on the Grid , i will need to pass same data to the data entry fields as well to provide edit and delete capabilities.

Please guide me know to do this. If you have references of similar project please send.

Comment: So, you're trying to implement master-detail in MVC?

Comment: No it is not master details . It is like in one page, i have to enter the data and on same page i will have to show /edit/delete the data..

Comment: Sounds like maybe you need some partial views and AJAX calls. jQuery can help with the AJAX calls.

Comment: do u any samples for this .. i can refer ..any url or samples??

Comment: Please provide the samples .. i need it urgently..

Comment: I don't have any off hand, do a little googling or searching of Overflow for examples on how to load partial views with AJAX/jQuery.

Comment: @Hemant For what you want to implement, you need to get the basics right about MVC. I would suggest you to go through a tutorial first, otherwise you will just be beating your head against a wall.